# Diagnose ObjectDisposedException "Safe handle has been closed"

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a C# application which is hitting an ObjectDisposedException with the message

> Safe handle has been closed

This happens as soon as I launch the application.

Sadly the stack trace is really unhelpful (see below). Is there any way for me to determine what call was being attempted asynchronously here?

Does DoAsyncCall() really imply an async method call?

> mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set() + 0xe bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage
>   msg) + 0x12f bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage
>   msg, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink replySink =
>   {System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult}) + 0x279 bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
>   + 0x32 bytes      mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(object
>   o) + 0x28 bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object
>   state) + 0x2f bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
>   state) + 0x6f bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback
>   tpWaitCallBack) + 0x53 bytes
>     mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(object
>   state) + 0x59 bytes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was caused by my use of a using(){} block.

```
    using (WaitHandle handle = asyncResponse.AsyncWaitHandle)
    {
      asyncResponse.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
      string response = asyncRequest.EndInvoke(asyncResponse);
      asyncResponse.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
      return response;
    }
```

When the calling thread is interrupted the using block is still calling Close on the WaitHandle.

Answer (score 17):

You are disposing something which is still being used by a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for this - is there any way to work out what I am disposing and what other thread is still using it?

Comment: @mchr: Debug, Break At Function, `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

Goofing around with security on API, and misspelled "Users":

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")] // exception...
```

> ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

Should have been:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Users")] // works!
```

A different error is thrown when group does not exist, like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeGroupThatDoesNotExist")]
```

> Win32Exception: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed

Comment: How is it related?